# Uploading files in Fine-Uploader, fail to combine/merge chunks after successful upload

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, fine-uploader, chunking

So I've been trying to get Chunked uploading working for a project I've been working on, I'm pretty new to things, in fact for all intensive purposes you can consider me a complete noob who is teaching himself, I'm using the Manual Upload Template from the website, and the Traditional Server Side Example files to gain an understanding of how the code works and trying to piece them together into a fully functional example for me to build from. I've been able to get most things working.

I've managed to get it uploading regular files into the files folder successfully if I upload a file without chunking it goes into my files directory, however if I use chunking it works to chunk up the file and upload it into a folder in my Chunks directory, but i cant seem to figure out how to get it to put the chunks back together and place it in the Files directory

My Firefox console gives me this response and stops after finishing uploading a file in chunks regardless of if I have my chunking success endpoint included in my code or not which makes me think it's got something to do with my chunking success endpoint not being set up correctly or something along those lines.

```
[Fine Uploader 5.11.8] All chunks have been uploaded for 0 - finalizing....fine-uploader.js:162:21
[Fine Uploader 5.11.8] Received response status 200 with body: {"success":true,"uuid":"79e7db33-9609-49cd-bcb1-2606bea6abd7","uploadName":null}fine-uploader.js:162:21
[Fine Uploader 5.11.8] Finalize successful for 0
```

I've spent about 2 days researching this with no avail, I don't seem to be getting errors, but as I said I'm pretty much a Noob when it comes to understanding this on my own. Any help is Greatly Appreciated.

Here Is my Uploader Code Body

```
    <body>
    <!-- Fine Uploader DOM Element
    ====================================================================== -->
    <div id="fine-uploader-manual-trigger"></div>

    <!-- Your code to create an instance of Fine Uploader and bind to the DOM/template
    ====================================================================== -->
    <script>
        var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                debug: true,
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
            template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
            request: {
                endpoint: 'endpoint.php'
            },
                chunking: {
                enabled: true
                },
                success:  { 
            endpoint: "endpoint.php?done"
                },
                resume: {
                enabled: true
                },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: 'images/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: 'images/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            autoUpload: false,
                showMessage: function(message) {  //show message if any error occur during upload process
                alert(message);
            }


        });

        qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
            manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here Is my Endpoint.php File

```
require_once "handler.php";


$uploader = new UploadHandler();

// Specify the list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
$uploader->allowedExtensions = array(); // all files types allowed by default

// Specify max file size in bytes.
$uploader->sizeLimit = null;

// Specify the input name set in the javascript.
$uploader->inputName = "qqfile"; // matches Fine Uploader's default inputName value by default

// If you want to use the chunking/resume feature, specify the folder to temporarily save parts.
$uploader->chunksFolder = "chunks";

$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if ($method == "POST") {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");

    // Assumes you have a chunking.success.endpoint set to point here with a query parameter of "done".
    // For example: /myserver/handlers/endpoint.php?done
    if (isset($_GET["done"])) {
        $result = $uploader->combineChunks("files");
    }
    // Handles upload requests
    else {
        // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload("files");

        // To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
        $result["uploadName"] = $uploader->getUploadName();
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
// for delete file requests
else if ($method == "DELETE") {
    $result = $uploader->handleDelete("files");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
}

?>
```

Here is my handler.php file, I'm just using the default traditional server side example.

```
class UploadHandler {

public $allowedExtensions = array();
public $sizeLimit = null;
public $inputName = 'qqfile';
public $chunksFolder = 'chunks';

public $chunksCleanupProbability = 0.001; // Once in 1000 requests on avg
public $chunksExpireIn = 604800; // One week

protected $uploadName;

/**
 * Get the original filename
 */
public function getName(){
    if (isset($_REQUEST['qqfilename']))
        return $_REQUEST['qqfilename'];

    if (isset($_FILES[$this->inputName]))
        return $_FILES[$this->inputName]['name'];
}

public function getInitialFiles() {
    $initialFiles = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
        array_push($initialFiles, array("name" => "name" + $i, uuid => "uuid" + $i, thumbnailUrl => ""));
    }

    return $initialFiles;
}

/**
 * Get the name of the uploaded file
 */
public function getUploadName(){
    return $this->uploadName;
}

public function combineChunks($uploadDirectory, $name = null) {
    $uuid = $_POST['qquuid'];
    if ($name === null){
        $name = $this->getName();
    }
    $targetFolder = $this->chunksFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$uuid;
    $totalParts = isset($_REQUEST['qqtotalparts']) ? (int)$_REQUEST['qqtotalparts'] : 1;

    $targetPath = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($uploadDirectory, $uuid, $name));
    $this->uploadName = $name;

    if (!file_exists($targetPath)){
        mkdir(dirname($targetPath), 0777, true);
    }
    $target = fopen($targetPath, 'wb');

    for ($i=0; $i<$totalParts; $i++){
        $chunk = fopen($targetFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$i, "rb");
        stream_copy_to_stream($chunk, $target);
        fclose($chunk);
    }

    // Success
    fclose($target);

    for ($i=0; $i<$totalParts; $i++){
        unlink($targetFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$i);
    }

    rmdir($targetFolder);

    if (!is_null($this->sizeLimit) && filesize($targetPath) > $this->sizeLimit) {
        unlink($targetPath);
        http_response_code(413);
        return array("success" => false, "uuid" => $uuid, "preventRetry" => true);
    }

    return array("success" => true, "uuid" => $uuid);
}

/**
 * Process the upload.
 * @param string $uploadDirectory Target directory.
 * @param string $name Overwrites the name of the file.
 */
public function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $name = null){

    if (is_writable($this->chunksFolder) &&
        1 == mt_rand(1, 1/$this->chunksCleanupProbability)){

        // Run garbage collection
        $this->cleanupChunks();
    }

    // Check that the max upload size specified in class configuration does not
    // exceed size allowed by server config
    if ($this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')) < $this->sizeLimit ||
        $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')) < $this->sizeLimit){
        $neededRequestSize = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';
        return array('error'=>"Server error. Increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to ".$neededRequestSize);
    }

    if ($this->isInaccessible($uploadDirectory)){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Uploads directory isn't writable");
    }

    $type = $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'])) {
        $type = $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'];
    }

    if(!isset($type)) {
        return array('error' => "No files were uploaded.");
    } else if (strpos(strtolower($type), 'multipart/') !== 0){
        return array('error' => "Server error. Not a multipart request. Please set forceMultipart to default value (true).");
    }

    // Get size and name
    $file = $_FILES[$this->inputName];
    $size = $file['size'];
    if (isset($_REQUEST['qqtotalfilesize'])) {
        $size = $_REQUEST['qqtotalfilesize'];
    }

    if ($name === null){
        $name = $this->getName();
    }

    // check file error
    if($file['error']) {
        return array('error' => 'Upload Error #'.$file['error']);
    }

    // Validate name
    if ($name === null || $name === ''){
        return array('error' => 'File name empty.');
    }

    // Validate file size
    if ($size == 0){
        return array('error' => 'File is empty.');
    }

    if (!is_null($this->sizeLimit) && $size > $this->sizeLimit) {
        return array('error' => 'File is too large.', 'preventRetry' => true);
    }

    // Validate file extension
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($name);
    $ext = isset($pathinfo['extension']) ? $pathinfo['extension'] : '';

    if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), array_map("strtolower", $this->allowedExtensions))){
        $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
        return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
    }

    // Save a chunk
    $totalParts = isset($_REQUEST['qqtotalparts']) ? (int)$_REQUEST['qqtotalparts'] : 1;

    $uuid = $_REQUEST['qquuid'];
    if ($totalParts > 1){
    # chunked upload

        $chunksFolder = $this->chunksFolder;
        $partIndex = (int)$_REQUEST['qqpartindex'];

        if (!is_writable($chunksFolder) && !is_executable($uploadDirectory)){
            return array('error' => "Server error. Chunks directory isn't writable or executable.");
        }

        $targetFolder = $this->chunksFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$uuid;

        if (!file_exists($targetFolder)){
            mkdir($targetFolder, 0777, true);
        }

        $target = $targetFolder.'/'.$partIndex;
        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->inputName]['tmp_name'], $target);

        return array("success" => true, "uuid" => $uuid);

    }
    else {
    # non-chunked upload

        $target = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($uploadDirectory, $uuid, $name));

        if ($target){
            $this->uploadName = basename($target);

            if (!is_dir(dirname($target))){
                mkdir(dirname($target), 0777, true);
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)){
                return array('success'=> true, "uuid" => $uuid);
            }
        }

        return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
            'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
    }
}

/**
 * Process a delete.
 * @param string $uploadDirectory Target directory.
 * @params string $name Overwrites the name of the file.
 *
 */
public function handleDelete($uploadDirectory, $name=null)
{
    if ($this->isInaccessible($uploadDirectory)) {
        return array('error' => "Server error. Uploads directory isn't writable" . ((!$this->isWindows()) ? " or executable." : "."));
    }

    $targetFolder = $uploadDirectory;
    $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $tokens = explode('/', $url);
    $uuid = $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-1];

    $target = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($targetFolder, $uuid));

    if (is_dir($target)){
        $this->removeDir($target);
        return array("success" => true, "uuid" => $uuid);
    } else {
        return array("success" => false,
            "error" => "File not found! Unable to delete.".$url,
            "path" => $uuid
        );
    }

}

/**
 * Returns a path to use with this upload. Check that the name does not exist,
 * and appends a suffix otherwise.
 * @param string $uploadDirectory Target directory
 * @param string $filename The name of the file to use.
 */
protected function getUniqueTargetPath($uploadDirectory, $filename)
{
    // Allow only one process at the time to get a unique file name, otherwise
    // if multiple people would upload a file with the same name at the same time
    // only the latest would be saved.

    if (function_exists('sem_acquire')){
        $lock = sem_get(ftok(__FILE__, 'u'));
        sem_acquire($lock);
    }

    $pathinfo = pathinfo($filename);
    $base = $pathinfo['filename'];
    $ext = isset($pathinfo['extension']) ? $pathinfo['extension'] : '';
    $ext = $ext == '' ? $ext : '.' . $ext;

    $unique = $base;
    $suffix = 0;

    // Get unique file name for the file, by appending random suffix.

    while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $unique . $ext)){
        $suffix += rand(1, 999);
        $unique = $base.'-'.$suffix;
    }

    $result =  $uploadDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $unique . $ext;

    // Create an empty target file
    if (!touch($result)){
        // Failed
        $result = false;
    }

    if (function_exists('sem_acquire')){
        sem_release($lock);
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Deletes all file parts in the chunks folder for files uploaded
 * more than chunksExpireIn seconds ago
 */
protected function cleanupChunks(){
    foreach (scandir($this->chunksFolder) as $item){
        if ($item == "." || $item == "..")
            continue;

        $path = $this->chunksFolder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item;

        if (!is_dir($path))
            continue;

        if (time() - filemtime($path) > $this->chunksExpireIn){
            $this->removeDir($path);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Removes a directory and all files contained inside
 * @param string $dir
 */
protected function removeDir($dir){
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item){
        if ($item == "." || $item == "..")
            continue;

        if (is_dir($item)){
            $this->removeDir($item);
        } else {
            unlink(join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($dir, $item)));
        }

    }
    rmdir($dir);
}

/**
 * Converts a given size with units to bytes.
 * @param string $str
 */
protected function toBytes($str){
    $val = trim($str);
    $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        case 'g': $val *= 1024;
        case 'm': $val *= 1024;
        case 'k': $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $val;
}

/**
 * Determines whether a directory can be accessed.
 *
 * is_executable() is not reliable on Windows prior PHP 5.0.0
 *  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-executable.php)
 * The following tests if the current OS is Windows and if so, merely
 * checks if the folder is writable;
 * otherwise, it checks additionally for executable status (like before).
 *
 * @param string $directory The target directory to test access
 */
protected function isInaccessible($directory) {
    $isWin = $this->isWindows();
    $folderInaccessible = ($isWin) ? !is_writable($directory) : ( !is_writable($directory) && !is_executable($directory) );
    return $folderInaccessible;
}

/**
 * Determines is the OS is Windows or not
 *
 * @return boolean
 */

protected function isWindows() {
    $isWin = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN');
    return $isWin;
}
```

}

Comment: Simply saying "it doesn't work", isn't enough to provide help. What _specifically_ is going wrong? What symptoms are you seeing? What log messages further illuminate the problem? Furthermore, the code you have included here is incomplete. Where is the code that attempts to handle the upload and combine the chunks?

Comment: My apologies, For all intensive purposes I'm pretty much a noob with this, Didn't realize I forgot to include my Handler.php, I have edited my question to include it, my firefox console response on a successful chunked upload, and tried to make my problem a little bit more clear, please let me know how I can make things easier to understand and if there is anything else I'm missing that would be beneficial to include. Basically I don't know how to get the chunked files to merge back together after being uploaded successfully,makes me think I'm not setting up my chunk Success endpoint correctly

Comment: Looks like your files are combined without issue.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that, from what I've seen and read my code should be set up to combine my files correctly, I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the problem in my setup, I just double checked my php.ini upload and post limits, restarted my apache server, restarted my computer just to make sure that wasn't the issue, no matter what i try, after a successful upload I'm always left with a randomly named folder in my chunks folder with a number of uncombined file chunks. Thanks again for having taken the time to respond, It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Combined files are stored in the uploads folder. And file folders are named based on uuid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help in making sure my code was correct, Kicked myself in the face for this one! As I was thinking for the longest time a incorrectly setup Apache Environment has been the root of all my problems.

I did not have .htaccess setup which seemed to fix all of my problems.

Here are the steps I followed to resolve my problem.

First Step

Open apache.conf file as

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Second Step

remove comment sign (#) if you find it before this line ( line number 187 approx.)

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Third Step

Then find the line where there is

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

replace "None" with "All"

```
AllowOverride All
```

Step Four

Activate ModRewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Everything should be Good from here.